# Shell insert line after last empty line

Tags: bash, shell, insert, sed

I'm trying to insert a line of text after the very last empty line in the middle of a file.

#### Example file:

```
some text
more text

blah blah blah
more blah

some more text
and even more text
```

The inserted text should be on line 6 for that file. I tried commands like this so far:

```
sed '/\n/ i some text' file
```

But, so far nothing has worked. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean: `last newline in the middle of a file`? Can you post your sample file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution with grep and awk:

```
awk -v last_empty_line=$(grep -nE '^[[:blank:]]*$' your_file | tail -1 | cut -c 1) '{print; if (NR==last_empty_line) print "->some new text here"}' your_file
```

awk inserts your new text after the last empty line; the index of the last empty line is selected with a proper grep which finds empty lines (or filled only with blank characters), piped into a tail to select the last one.

Comment: Very nice, the idea of going twice through the file is the simplest approach for this quirky problem. What about this simplification: `index=$(grep -ne '^$' | tail -n 1); sed $index's/.*/yourline\n&/';`. (Note that I removed the `cut -c 1` which makes your line wrong)

Comment: The regexp in grep is more complex to take into account blank non-empty lines; so you can omit this of course.
I test it on cygwin, my grep -n outputs the line number followed by a column. I want to cut it quickly and I make it wrong :(. Let's pipe it into a sed or grep for removing it.
However, your solution is more elegant, I don't know that you can apply sed commands on specific lines like this. So +1 for your final solution.

Comment: My awk -n also outputs the number followed by a colon. Therefore his is right and yours is wrong. The cut command is needed.

Comment: A better way to do it: `index=$(grep -ne '^$' $nFile | tail -n 1 | sed "s/://")
 sed -i $index"i $End_Text" $nFile;`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
perl -p00e 'eof&&s/^/-- new text --\n\n/' text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed ':a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba;p;d};s/^/-> some text\n/' file
```